# Document-level content of a full-text index of Persian Language

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing, persian

I want to extract words in a full indexed column in the Persian Language. I used sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document to get them. It works, But the extracted words are in Arabic Alphabet, for example, "عربسةان" instead of "عربستان".
I should mention that I examined several collations including Persian, Arabic, and Latin.